# how to pull a specific slice of ampiechart at page load,

Tags: javascript, pie-chart, amcharts, donut-chart

this is a sample code . for ex i want to pull **Germany** slice on page load. in this code it pull first slice .
    var chart;
    var legend;
    var chartData = [{
    country: "Lithuania",
    value: 260},
     {
    country: "Ireland",
    value: 201},
     {
    country: "Germany",
    value: 65},
     {
    country: "Australia",
    value: 39},
    {
    country: "UK",
    value: 19},
    {
    country: "Latvia",
    value: 10}];

```
AmCharts.ready(function() {
// PIE CHART
chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();
chart.dataProvider = chartData;
chart.titleField = "country";
chart.valueField = "value";
chart.labelText = "[[title]]";

chart.handDrawn = true;
chart.outlineColor = "#FFFFFF";
chart.outlineAlpha = 0.8;
chart.outlineThickness = 2;
chart.pulledField= "country";  
chart.pullOutOnlyOne = true;
// this makes the chart 3D
chart.depth3D = 15;
chart.angle = 30;

chart.write(chartdiv);
 });
```

......................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

You have just about got it right.  You just need to change the **chart.pulledField** variable to be a new data value and then include this data value in the **chartData**.

You can see a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/ou7gytm6/2/

The change to your chartDate is...

```
var chartData = [{ country: "Lithuania", value: 260}, 
                 { country: "Ireland", value: 201}, 
                 { country: "Germany", value: 65, "pullOut": true}, 
                 { country: "Australia", value: 39}, 
                 { country: "UK", value: 19}, 
                 { country: "Latvia", value: 10}];
```

And the change your chart.pulledField is...

```
chart.pulledField= "pullOut";
```